# What user friendly subdomain should I use with an existing site?

Tags: subdomain

I am developing a login and account system for use with an existing website, this will run on a subdomain under the main site url.
I would like to use a subdomain that is generic enough so it isn't tied to an account system but not off-putting to users.

I was thinking of www2 but I am concerned people will see this and think its not "legitimate".

Thanks

Some more context.
The new site is currently used for the login and account system but I will eventually migrate the whole website to the new system, this means the services and pages served by the subdomain will very a lot so it can't be specific to one thing.

Answer (score 1):

Try something generic in the interest / knowledge domain of the existing website. What does the existing website do or provide? This can help you determine a proper subdomain.

Some generic examples:

- info.domain.com
- account.domain.com
- auth.domain.com
- app.domain.com
- to.domain.com

Providing a better subdomain is going to require some more context.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I have added some more info to the question but basically I want to serve account functions as well as information, content, jobs and company data so the name has to be generic enough hence my thought of 'www2'. I am currently using 'data' but I think I need to change this.